# Not able to sync dependency in build.gradle in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to use some native library. and I am using below dependnecy

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.+'

in build.gradle in flutter project.

How I will sync that dependency. Please help me!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using Android Studio for Flutter development, right click on the android folder in your Flutter project. Select "Flutter" -> "Open Android Module in Android Studio".

Or

Simply start Android Studio and open the Android (sub)project directly.

In any case, once the Android project is opened in Android Studio, you can make changes in your build.gradle. The editor will tell you to sync. Otherwise simply execute a build. Afterwards you will be able to import use your Android classes.

Comment: After adding the dependency in an android folder and run ./gradlew build under android folder ... still, I am not able to import classes.

Comment: I do not get a prompt to sync once I update my gradle. Is there a way to do manually?

Answer (score 13):

That is the problem with gradle sync of Android project, not with Flutter dependencies.

In your build.gradle of your module (for example android/app/build.gradle of your Flutter project) add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.+'
```

in dependencies as bellow:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Then open terminal, cd to `android` folder of your flutter project and run:

```
$./gradlew build
```

After that you will be able import `com.google.android.gms...` in your Java class.

Comment: I already integrated channel to communicate from flutter to native .
I want to implement native library code and use native library result into a flutter.
Please help me how to implement native library into android like use java dependency and use the result of native library code.

Comment: So what is your problem? You can call or do whatever with library (google play service) in your java code. And then communicate with Flutter via platform channel. Can you post a simple code that you are working with here?

Comment: Actually when I adding dependency in build.gradle ... I am not able to import the class in activity.. and also not able to sync dependency in build.gradle file ....

Comment: With command line in Android root project, try run command

./gradlew build

Comment: This is not a problem with Flutter. Treat the project as normal Android project. Try to sync gradle from command line, it will resolve your problem.

Comment: After adding the dependency in an android folder and run ./gradlew build under android folder ... still, I am not able to import classes.

Comment: What IDE do you use? Try to open it in Android Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185485/discussion-between-shruti-majajan-and-linh).

Answer (score 4):

Go to **android** folder of your flutter project and then

open it in terminal by right clicking on that folder

then try to run below command

**gradlew build**

Answer (score 1):

i know i am late but let me suggest the way as per i done and it's working , if it helps to someone

1. Open android studio flutter project
2. Go to file
3. Click on setting
4. Search for "Flutter"
5. at bottom of that view there is an experiments section do check that both checkbox

after doing this add any dependencies in android gradle and go to file and click on "Sync with file system" and you are done , please check the below screenshot to do check the experiments item

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sync the dependencies using "Run Configurations". Please follow next screenshots:

1. Open Gradle tab.
   [image]
2. Select path to Build.Gradle file.
   [image]
3. Double click to sync.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the kotlin version being specified in the `build.gradle`, which wasn't in sync with the IDE's version. Changed it from `ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'`. Now it is syncing the gradle script again.

[image]