# ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' error after adding firebase auth plugin in flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am getting some errors after installing the `firebase_auth` plugin and updating the other `firebase` plugin versions. I tried some solutions including downgrading the firebase auth plugin version and adding some lines to my gradle files but it is still not working.

**pubspec.yaml**:

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  json_annotation: ^1.2.0
  geolocator: ^2.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^0.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^2.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.2+1
  firebase_messaging: ^3.0.1
  flutter_advanced_networkimage: any
  image_picker: ^0.4.10
  url_launcher: ^4.0.1
  multi_image_picker: ^2.2.30
  intl: ^0.15.7
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  sqflite: ^1.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.20.0
```

**gradle.properties**:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**app/build.gradle**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId ****************
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0' //added this as per comment below

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'//added this as per comment below

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'//added this as per comment below

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-service
```

**Error**:

```
    Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.6.2+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.3.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemessaging\FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
         *********************************************************
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1

....message to visit a link....

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: some directory path ending with.jar,
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing my error by following this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27128#issuecomment-457918930

Here's some other notes:

1. When updating the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties I used 4.10.2. Your version might be different depending when you do this I'm guessing.
2. If you can't find the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" command follow this [Not able to sync dependency in build.gradle in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834085/not-able-to-sync-dependency-in-build-gradle-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

Man i had a problem like this just one day ago. This is probably conflict between support library and androidx in your dependencies. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27106) issue. In my case i solve this manually removing all dependencies from my project in pubspec and add one by one with new updated version that already use androidx and migrate my project too. Well i try IDE androidX migration tool but without success. Finally be aware with thrid part libraries some of them take a time to update and create problems like this.

Comment: I came across that issue thread as well, eventually I had to do what you just mentioned following steps in a link I posted in my answer. It seemed to fix my error, hopefully nothing else pops up.

Comment: I spend an entire day to solve this problem, hopefully we got solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your whole firebase plugins as new

Comment: Not sure what you mean as upgrade as new, can you elaborate?

Comment: Update to new version of cloud_firestore, firebase_auth etc which are related to firebase, I solved by this

Comment: I updated to the latest plugin versions still an error

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and i updated as follows

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

Check latest version and update accordingly 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: So I should put this in app/build.gradle?

Comment: I'm still getting an error, I updated my answer with the lines of code in my app/build.grade file.