# D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and i build a very little app showing current latitude and longitude which required me to add two dependencies in pubspec.yaml :-

location and simple_permissions to get current user location and asking for location permission.

but when i ran the app it shows following error:-

```
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /home/letsdoit/IdeaProjects/location/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i think it is because of adding a library two times but i am not adding dependencies manually so it is flutter error inside.

Please tell me solution of it

Output Of ./gradlew app:dependecies is as follows:-

```
+--- project :location
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+ -> 15.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |              |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|         |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- project :simple_permissions
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.71
          +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.2.71
          \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
```

build.gradle for my app is as follows :-

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "ab"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

pubspec.yaml :-

```
name: a
description: b

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler: ^2.2.0
  location: ^2.0.0



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean/49767860) may help.

Comment: can you tell us the version of your dependencies?

Comment: i can show you the output of ./gradlew app:dependencies

Comment: i have added it you can see

Answer (score 6):

This gradle error messages are so hard to solve... Well I had some problems like this  and I wrote how I solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700564/apptransformdexarchivewithexternallibsdexmergerfordebug-error-after-adding-f/54718261#54718261). Anyway I advise you to use updated packages in your pubspec.  simple_permissions package has been a while there is no updates, try [permission_handler](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler) package instead. Other point to avoid future build problems is migrate your app to androidX and use dependencies which already using androidX too, a lot of official plugins are migrating to it and when we mix support library with androidX in the same project the build process fails sadly. If you are planning include google_maps in you app I really recommend you migrate to androidX instead avoid it.

AndroidX is the original support library packages and classes with other namespace. Full description [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/).

You can migrate to androidx manually or you can use android-studio migration tool that some times fails. A migration process with android-studio tools has been already described [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27128#issuecomment-457918930) in details.

To migrate manually you need replace all your support library dependencies by respective androidx package. An example is:

```
dependencies {
   // using support library
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$version' 
}
```

Must be replaced by

```
dependencies {
       // using androidx
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$version' //androidx artifact 
    }
```

Androidx artifact mappings can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings)
In your gradle.properties file you need insert this two lines below

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

And make sure your flutter dependencies are using androix too.

Take a look at [this](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) flutter page it talks about androidX compatibility and migration.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your help buddy, let me try and tell me how can i migrate it to androidX . i don't know what it is.

Comment: implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
i have this in my dependecies

Comment: can you post your gradle.build for your app module and your pubspec file?

Comment: Ok let me post then

Comment: I have posted it please check it

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem

added this in gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true 
android.useAndroidX=true
```

In `build.gradle` (app level)
Removed  : implementation `'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`

added :

```
implementation `"androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.+"`
```

and Run Clean and Invalidate Cache & Restart - worked out

Answer (score 3):

Using Ionic, solved by adding following plugins

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the plugin cordova-plugin-mfilechooser, that did not use androidx already (using Phonegap)