# Flutter packages using same class (how to solve class conflict?)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, mobile, dart

I use this two packages:

```
barcode_scan: ^0.0.3
fluttie: ^0.3.0
```

When I try to run my application, I get the following error:

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:  /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/111.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/126.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/57.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/160.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/56.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/91.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/81.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/156.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/59.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/157.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/141.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/101.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/94.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/159.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/116.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/95.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/158.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/151.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/136.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/146.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/92.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/131.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/93.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/106.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/121.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/rhuka/repository/github/learn/flutter/flutter_lottie_signup/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Seems to me that both of them use the same class `android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel` because when I try to use only one of them everything works fine. But I need both on my application. How can I ignore the duplicated classes or just solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771498/d8-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-media-mediabrowsercompatcu

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same sort of conflict with `qr_code_scanner` the solution is to delete or change classes for one of them I don't know if flutter has built-in method to handle this sort of conflicts.
but what you can try is to get package from git repo do the changes push the code to your own repo and pub get from your own git repo:

```
dependencies:
  fluttie:
     git:
       url: https://github.com/...
       ref: main
```

Comment: if you find any easier way please inform me too tnx :)

Comment: Ouch, four years later someone finally answered that :')
Unfortunately I didn't proceed with the project, decided to do it with RN, but I'll revive this for sure when I have some time, thanks for the answer xD