# When I include google maps my build fails

Tags: google-maps, build, flutter

When I include a "google maps" dependency into pubspec.yaml

```
google_maps_flutter: ^0.2.0+3
```

my build fails with:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$ConnectionCallbackInternal
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of google_maps_flutter will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See xxxxxxxxxxx for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\95.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\105.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\110.jar, C:\Users\philb\flutter_course2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115.jar

Can someone point me in the right direction to understand and track this down. This project built just fine previously.

Comment: Have you ran the flutter packages get

Comment: yes I have - I run it every time I comment in and out google maps or add another dependency

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have in your app google_maps_plugin version that is using androidx and probably your app and/or some other dependency is using android support library.  I had provided some ways to solve this kind of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700564/apptransformdexarchivewithexternallibsdexmergerfordebug-error-after-adding-f/54718261#54718261) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771498/d8-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-media-mediabrowsercompatcu/54773290#54773290).
But what you need to do is [migrate all your app to androidx](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx) and use updated dependencies versions that already has been migrated too.

Other way is [avoid androidx](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx) making downgrade of your dependencies packages for versions pre androidx.

For more details about flutter apps androidx migration see the original docs [reference](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#fixing-androidx-crashes-in-a-flutter-app)

I hope it helps.