# How to fix the error where in flutter when I open the app level build gradle, errors start to show up, now

Tags: android, gradle, build

I can't connect my app to Google Firebase and I need to see somethings in that build gradle file. When I open the app level build gradle, I get errors, I am trying to connect my app to Google Firebase but when I open my app normally, I see no errors at all and everything is going just fine and I can still run my app on the Android Emulator, but when I go ahead and open the file, errors start to pop up and I am unable to run my app, here is my app level build gradle for Android:

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}


def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.appbrewery.flash_chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flut

ter {
        source '../..'
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
```

I am unable to understand the problem. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to sync dependency in build.gradle in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834085/not-able-to-sync-dependency-in-build-gradle-in-flutter)

Comment: The issue turns out to be related to firebase at that time with security rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the gradle files in the flutter project. You have to click on Tools --> Flutter --> Open Android Module in Android Studio. Then you can edit the graddle, run the app and come back to the flutter project with no errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue turns out to be missing network permission required for Firebase services to work.

Answer (score 0):

[works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g44JT.png)

Goto : Tools -> Flutter -> Open Flutter Module in Android Studio -> Make changes in build gradle

Comment: where its gradle file exist in flutter sdk please tell me